What happens when node quotas conflict after multiple schedulers are used simultaneously in k8s?
I tried to use multiple schedulers in k8s, such as the default scheduler and the volcano scheduler, they manage the same node resources.
I wonder what will happen if two pods are scheduled to the same node by different schedulers at the same time? The node has enough resources to host one pod, but it cannot host two pods.
For example, a 128core machine is assigned two pods with total 256core requirements.

Will pod fail directly? Or any other?

Thanks in advance, k8s experts!

Both schedulers can run together but your pod (or pods) will be allocated accordingly depending on the pod spec. This won't affect the kubelet at all in terms of crashing. From docs:

Note: To determine if a scheduler is responsible for scheduling a
specific Pod, the spec.schedulerName field in a PodTemplate or Pod
manifest must match the schedulerName field of the
KubeSchedulerProfile. All schedulers running in the cluster must have
unique names.

If you don't specify anything in the pod spec, it will default to the Kubernetes default scheduler.
Basically, the schedulers follow a control loop if one pod is allocated by one scheduler on a node and the next time a different scheduler tries to allocate a pod on the same node if the node doesn't have enough capacity it won't be able to be scheduled.  Any race condition with regards to state would be handle by the state storage which in Kubernetes happens to be etcd. etcd uses the raft consensus algorithm to handle race conditions.

Thanks, but what I mean is that two pods are scheduled to the same node by different schedulers at the same time. The node has enough resources to host one pod, but it cannot host two pods. Generally, this kind of scheduling does not happen in one single scheduler scenario, but it happens now due to parallelism conflicts.

I can't see that happening. Do you have a specific example? Schedulers are on service loop FIFO.

Added more details. I suggest you learn about some of the deep kubernetes fundamentals.
